# ModuleNotFoundError Only when EXE (Python)

Tags: python, user-interface, pyinstaller, exe, pysimplegui

I am trying to make a program using PySimpleGUI and whenever I run it as a .py (Python) file I get 0 errors and it runs exactly how I want it to, but when I use *pyinstaller* to compile the .py file to an EXE I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "guitest.py", line 2, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySimpleGUI'
[14792] Failed to execute script guitest
```

I am not sure why it is saying that, I have it installed. As I said before as long as it's a .py file it runs perfectly.

Comment: If you are using pyinstaller it will compile external modules (like PySimpleGUI). But if PySimpleGui imports other modules, the compiler will throw an error. Would be helpful if you could offer a few more information (like which compiler you use or which modules you have imported

Comment: @MichaelBrown The other modules I have import are these: os, threading, shutil, sys

Comment: I do not mean the other modules you've imported, but the ones that PySimpleGui inported itself